# Conflict dayClick and height declaration FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm tryin' with FullCalendar. But when I add 'height' property into the initialize function, the dayClick function doesn't work, then I remove height, it works normally. Could you please explain to me why and how to set height for calendar.
Here is my code:

```
$(tag).fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: date,
    editable: true,
  //height: 'auto',
    header: {
        left: 'today prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    buttonText: {
        today: 'Today'
    },
    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        //code
    },

});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid syntax, take out the comma after dayClick.

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    //code
}
```